# WPF Frame and Page Get event

Tags: wpf, events

Is that possible in wpf, in main window will capture the event of the page inside the frame element?

```
 <Window>
   <Grid>
     <TextBlock x:Name="lblEvent"/>
     <Frame Source="Page1.xaml"/>
   </Grid>
</Window>

<Page>
   <Grid>
        <Button Content="Click Me"/>
   </Grid>
</Page>
```

If the button has been clicked, the textblock in the main window will update the text to "Page1 Button click".

Answer (score 0):

If you use MVVM patter this would be very easy:

Define your ViewModel class:

```
class MyViewModel:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   private string _LabelText;
   public string LabelText
    {
        get
        {
            return this._LabelText;
        }

        set
        {
            if (value != this._LabelText)
            {
                this._LabelText = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    private DelegateCommand _ClickCommand;
    public readonly DelegateCommand ClickCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if(_ClickCommand == null)
            {
                _ClickCommand = new DelegateCommand(()=>LabelText="LabelText Changed!");            
            }   
            return _ClickCommand;
        }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your Window set the `DataContext`:

```
public class MainWindow
{
    private MyViewModel vm;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.vm = new MyViewModel()
        DataContext = vm;
    }
}
```

Set the binding inside the View Code:

```
<Window>
   <Grid>
     <TextBlock x:Name="lblEvent" Text="{Binding LabelText}"/>
     <Frame Source="Page1.xaml"/>
   </Grid>
</Window>

<Page>
   <Grid>
        <Button Content="Click Me" Command="{Binding ClickCommand}"/>
   </Grid>
</Page>
```

As you can see there is any event delegate, but just a command that handle the click of the button. You can find more informations here: [Mvvm Basics](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/msgulfcommunity/2013/03/13/understanding-the-basics-of-mvvm-design-pattern/); [Commands](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn237302.aspx); [Prism Command](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1055060/DelegateCommand-and-CompositeCommand-in-Prism)