# How to go back to main window from page in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

On a C# application that I am working on, I have a frame on my main window.

```
<Frame x:Name="frame" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden"/>
```

I click a button on my main window, and then I use the frame that I created to navigate to a page using the code below.

```
//Create a new object for the page
CameraPage camera = new CameraPage();

//Navigate to the new page
frame.NavigationService.Navigate(camera);
```

What I would like to do is if I click a button on the **camera page** that is contained within the frame, then it only exits the page while still keeping the main window intact.

I have tried something like this.

`NavigationService.GoBack();`

But then I get an error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cannot navigate because there is no entry in the Back stack of the journal.'

I believe this error is happening because the navigation stack I used to go the page is apart of the **main window** code and not the page that I navigated to.

So my question really is, how do I close a page contained within a frame with a button contained within the page, without closing the entire application?

Comment: Is the initial `Button` that you click inside the `Frame` or outside it?

Comment: The initial button that I press is outside the frame, but I also have it contained within a stackpanel, which is something I forgot to mention in the question.

Comment: Alright, and is there something else in the `Frame` before the button click, or is it jsut sitting there empty? Or is it hidden?

Comment: The frame is normally empty, until I fill it with the new page using the code I posted above.

Comment: @AaronJones: Did you try `Window.GetWindow(this) as MainWindow)?.frame.NavigationService.GoBack()`? What does the `CanGoBack` property return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to end up with an empty `Frame` again, all you have to do is clear the `Frame`'s contents. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6488787/5086631), you can do so like this:

```
frame.Content = null;
```

That will get you back to how things started, now you just to trigger it. For that, I'll refer you to the question [WPF Frame and Page Get event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51646900/wpf-frame-and-page-get-event). The answer there shows you how to use `DelegateCommand` (a.k.a. `RelayCommand`) to accomplish this. This is the way I would go, because it keeps the `Page` nice and separate from whatever `Window` is hosting it.

Technically, you could also pass your `Page` a reference to `frame` when you initialize it, then have it set `frame.Content = null;` that way. But that's a sort of "quick and dirty" approach, not really a best practice.